# Nginx changes POST to GET using proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, post, proxy

I want to use Nginx create a gateway to receive requests and pass them along to a network of microservices.

What I need Nginx to do is just act as a proxy server, taking the requests, passing them along to whatever service, and returning the response without any changes.

This is my configuration for my local setup:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location /api/register/ {
        proxy_pass http://micro_auth_backend:8082;
    }

    location /api/location/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8088;
    }

}
```

It works correctly for GET requests, but when doing a POST call, the server will always receive a GET response.

I have tried adding some more configs inside the location, such as this example below, but so far nothing has worked:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Did you try proxy_method to forcibly change request method？

Comment: I want to forward the request with whatever method it comes, so doing a `proxy_method POST` is no good. I tried `proxy_method $request_method` but this results in nginx forwarding the name of the variable as the method instead of the value of the variable. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just removed the trailing slash on location:

```
location /api/register {
    proxy_pass http://micro_auth_backend:8082;
}
```

Now it works.

Comment: I misread and removed the trailing slash on the proxy_pass URL, but that actually did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code to your nginx.conf file. It works for me.

```
location /api/register/ {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8082;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location /api/location/ {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8088;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it but it is still changing the POST to GET