# AWS Amplify redirect change from post to get?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-amplify

I'm trying to connect to my backend api, usually anything that is /intApi/<*> gets sends over to different api.domain.com. but for some reason the request changes from post to get.
+
I'm using nginx to do

```
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api.domain.com www.api.domain.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
server {  
   listen 443 ssl;
   listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;
   server_name api.domain.com www.api.domain.com;
   
   ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/live/api.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/api.domain.com/privkey.pem;
   ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

   location / {
           proxy_pass http://backendDocker:3500/;
   }

   location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
       root /usr/share/nginx/web/api;
   }
}
```

To push it further and nginx output is either OPTIONS or GET instead of POST.
What am I doing wrong here? I tried 301/302 redirects. Same issue :/

Comment: Removing the trailing slash  after `:3500` in `proxy_pass` seems to fix the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68991584/nginx-changes-post-to-get-using-proxy-pass

Comment: Hey
We figured it out at the end. The problem was with ssl certificate. We did some certificates on api.domain, and then updated certificate. That did not work with aws. We had to change to api.domainX and then back to api.domain to force reload handshake/cache in aws and after that it worked for any1 wondering.

Comment: That's great to hear @Dariusz